# Getting multiple authentication errors from MS graph endpoints across different tenants

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have a multitenant application, which is getting authentication errors on 30-40 % of the requests today, and there are no warning on azure status page or office status page.
This is cripling our application a lot.

Anymore else experiencing this?

I assume that there are still no where else to report Graph issues than here?

Comment: Could this be releated to MS changing O365 licenses today?

Comment: We had similar issues yesterday and it does seem to be related to the license changes. Many of our tenants just ended up re-authenticating and the issue did not come back.